# Angular - How to use ngIf on async value

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

Apologies for what might seem like a basic question.
 Is there a way to only show the wrapper div if the '`album_title`' value exists? Below is what I've tried so far.

```
    <div *ngIf="album?.album_title">
        <div> Album </div>
        <div> {{ (album | async)?.album_title }} </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="album?.album_date">
        <div> Album Date</div>
        <div> {{ (album | async)?.album_date }} </div>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="album?.album_rating">
        <div> Album Rating</div>
        <div> {{ (album | async)?.album_rating }} </div>
    </div>
```

**Update**
Updated to clearly show multiple values might be present.

**UPDATE**: Answer based on Saravanan Nandhan response

```
  <div *ngIf="album | async as album">
    <div *ngIf="album.album_title">
      <div> Album Titel </div>
      <div> {{ album.album_title }} </div>
    </div>
   <div *ngIf="album.album_date">
      <div> Album Date </div>
      <div> {{ album.album_date }} </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: have you tried `*ngIf="album.album_title`

Comment: Hi @user3284463 - Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, Yes, I have :)

Comment: if album is of type Observable then you may use <div *ngIf="(album|async)?.album_title">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of waiting for each `album$ | async` operation to be fully available, which likely requires more conditional checking further down inside the child presentational components, we can adopt a slightly different approach:

```
<div *ngIf="album$ | async as album">
  <div> Album </div>
  <div> {{ album.album_title }} </div>
</div>
```

Note the addition of `as album` at the end of the expression.

What this will do is wait until `album$ | async` has evaluated, and bind the result to the value of `album` (non-dollar-suffixed).

PS - You might want to change the property name on your Component Class from `album` to `album$`

> The `prop$` dollar suffix is generally used to indicate something is an
>   Observable source.

Comment: Thanks @Saravanan - I don't fully understand the reference to 'the user'. I've given this a go anyway, and it doesn't work i'm afraid. Say I have multiple album attributes such as a title, date, comment, review etc etc each having their own wrapper divs with a label / title. How would your approach ensure that those individual wrapper divs are only displayed when each field contains a value?

Comment: @Que, he was just giving an example. I've updated the answer. Please read it again.

Comment: @SiddAjmera Thnks for updating :)

Comment: Thanks Both. I've updated my question. I don't want a 'global' wrapper to be hidden. It's per value. I'm assuming your response is to hide the entire Div if there isn't an 'album' opposed to just the title, date etc?

Comment: @Que, your implementation is going to unwrap the `album` observable again and again but will eventually give the same value. So there's no added value doing it your way.

Comment: Thanks @SiddAjmera - Maybe I haven't articulated what I'm trying to achieve particularly well. If each piece of metadata I have has certain CSS styling and padding etc, I only want to render each metadata div if it exists. Otherwise there are style implications and the metadata label / title in the HTML will be visible with no content. All i want to do is check if each individual piece exists, and if it doesn't, don't show that particular HTML segment.

Comment: But why keep Title and Content in two different `div`s. Why not just create a wrapping `div` with two different `p`s or `span`s or whatever? Is the lable and the actual value styled differently?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. I have one wrapper div per item. Inside, the first div inside is the label. That has styling applicable to all my labels. The second div inside is the content. That has styles that are applicable to my content. I simply what to do a check on the wrapper div of that item (where I've stuck *ngIf) to show and hide that segment depending on if there's a value. It's only today that I've decided to try and code it differently. Previously I just used *ngIf="album_title" and that worked. If it's that difficult to achieve then I might just forget about it.

Comment: I've updated my question with the answer mixed in with yours on how I got it to work. Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 4):

It is missing ending " (double quote)

```
*ngIf="album?.album_title
```

Change it as below

```
<div *ngIf="album?.album_title">
    <div> Album </div>
    <div> {{ (album | async)?.album_title }} </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried that too :( - Thanks for pointing that out though, that was a typo when entering it into StackOverflow, opposed to any code

Comment: if album is of type Observable then you may use <div *ngIf="(album|async)?.album_title">